# Best way to handle non-English characters in JSON files while communicating with the server?

Tags: android, json, unicode, utf-8, character-encoding

The mobile app I coded creates various JSON objects and sends them to the server, but when these JSON objects's strings include Turkish letters etc, the strings received by the server becomes unreadable.

How can one fix this? I have access to the server side as well as the mobile app.

Comment: JSON is intended to be encoded in UTF-8 when transmitted or saved to disk.  And even then, there is a syntax in JSON for hex-encoding Unicode characters when raw characters are not used. So, either you are not encoding your JSON correctly when sending it, or the server is not handling the encoding correctly when reading it. Either way, there is no way anyone here can diagnose your problem with the limited information you have provided so far. Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, and show the actual data on both ends.